# Django - Clean permission table

Tags: django, permissions

During development apps and models permissions are sometimes removed or renamed. What's a good way to clean the leftovers from the permissions table without breaking something?

For example: I have an app `articles` with model `Article` with some permissions.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = ...
    text = ...

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_edit_title', 'Can edit title of article'),
            ('can_edit_text', 'Can edit text of article'),
        )
```

I add this permission by command (with installed `django_extension`):

```
./manage update_permissions
```

But later I realise, that it would be better to name it `can_update_title`. So I change the model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_update_title', 'Can update title of article'),
            ('can_update_text', 'Can update text of article'),
        )
```

When I update permissions there are both permissions in Django administration and it is really confusing for users - administrators.

Comment: You're question is a little vague, mind elaborating with a little bit of context?

Comment: Ok, I have written little bit more.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Short answer:** register the Permission with the admin site. add this to your admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
admin.site.register(Permission)
```

Then you control everything from there.

**Long answer:** Permission are objects, just like everything else in django. They are *saved into the database*, and linked linked to users and groups through a ManyToMany relationship. When you simply changed the name of the permission in the Meta class of the Article model, django had no way of knowing that you still ment the same object as before, so instead it created a new one.

What you should've done was, after changing the name of the permission in the model was to also change the name of the correlating permission object in your database.

The easiest way to do this is to register the Permission object with the admin site, so you'd have control from there. You'd still need to change it in both places (models.py and your DB) for any name change, but the admin site makes this easier.

**Keep in mind** that the extra Permission object you created ('update') has a new pk, meaning that if you just delete your older Permission object ('edit') it would have consequences on anything it had a relation with. If you have data that you don't want to lose I suggest writing a script to *merge* the two Permission objects to avoid any errors

Comment: That's a bit clearer. did you try simply deleting the old permissions? Also, why did you need the extension, in what way wasn't the default enough?

Comment: Removing old permissions directly in DB is complicated - we have multiple machines, so I would have to write some script. It is of course solution, but I hoped there is a simple one. We use `django_extension` because (I think) in default is not automatic update of permission. + I forgot, we use also `django-guardian` to connect permission with objects.

Comment: For those who don't know how to use the two suggested lines: you can add them to any admin.py (if you have more than one app) and then go with the browser to BASE_URL/admin/auth/permission

Answer (score 2):

A Django builtin management command exists that takes care of removing/deleting stale content types - and while deleting stale content types this command also deletes related permissions:

```sh
./manage.py remove_stale_contenttypes [--include-stale-apps]
```

It also takes an optional argument `--include-stale-apps` which results in:

> "Deletes stale content types including ones from previously installed
> apps that have been removed from INSTALLED_APPS."

Quoted from the command help text. Official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#remove-stale-contenttypes

This command lets the user confirm the hits (content types and permissions) and you also have the option to answer "No, don't do anything" each time; example:

```sh
./manage.py remove_stale_contenttypes --include-stale-apps
Some content types in your database are stale and can be deleted.
Any objects that depend on these content types will also be deleted.
The content types and dependent objects that would be deleted are:

    - Content type for core.affiliation
    - 4 auth.Permission object(s)
    ...

This list doesn't include any cascade deletions to data outside of Django's
models (uncommon).

Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Some content types in your database are stale and can be deleted.
Any objects that depend on these content types will also be deleted.
The content types and dependent objects that would be deleted are:

    - Content type for foo.bar
    - 3 auth.Permission object(s)
    - 3 auth.Group_permissions object(s)
    - Content type for foo.baz
    - 3 auth.Permission object(s)
    - 6 auth.Group_permissions object(s)
    ...

This list doesn't include any cascade deletions to data outside of Django's
models (uncommon).

Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Some content types in your database are stale and can be deleted.
Any objects that depend on these content types will also be deleted.
The content types and dependent objects that would be deleted are:

    - Content type for misc.whatever
    - 4 auth.Permission object(s)
    ...

This list doesn't include any cascade deletions to data outside of Django's
models (uncommon).

Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
```