# Django admin console keeps listing permissions that were removed from the model

Tags: django, django-models, permissions

I have a Patient model for which, by default, the 'add_patient', 'change_patient' and 'delete_patient' permissions are added to the database. I also wanted to add a 'view_patient' but I accidentally specified it as 'app.view_patient' because my app is called 'app' and in any other place but the models you need to put this identifier in front of the permission string in order to indicate a class-level permission. Turned out that this permission was internally translated to 'app.app.view_patient' because Django automatically attaches the 'app' identifier for model permissions.

I realised my mistake so I tried to change the permission to just 'view_patient' but for some reason the admin console keep listing the previous permission even though I ran several model migrations where there is no additional permissions specified on the Patient model.

I was wondering whether anyone has encountered this problem before, where the admin page does not sync well with the newly migrated models.

Cheers,

Comment: Wow, that was fast :) I'll do that, thanks for the tip!

Comment: There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858199/django-clean-permission-table), with the clever suggestion to register the `Permission` model in the Django admin to make it easy to edit/delete permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Django doesn't manually detect or remove stale permissions from the database.

The easiest way to fix the problem might be to remove them from the `auth_permission` database table using the db shell (or a GUI tool if you already use one).

If you need to automate this, you could import the [`Permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#permission-model) model from `django.contrib.auth.models` and then filter and delete the stale permissions.

Comment: That indeed sounds like a very helpful feature in the admin console